# "syntactically incorrect" error when submitting Oozie jobs to HDInsight using Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: oozie, azure-hdinsight, oozie-coordinator

Invoke-RestMethod : HTTP Status 400 - 
type Status report
message 
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You can validate your xml file with `oozie validate workflow.xml`

Comment: It helped troubleshooting malformed input error while submitting the oozie job remotely - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

- The workflow.xml or the coordinator.xml has some problems.  For example, E1003 Invalid coordinator application attributes, Coordinator Start Time cannot be greater than End Time.
- A variable defined in the workflow.xml or the coordinator.xml is not found in the payload.